# SSRS report with Multi value parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report developed using SSRS that contain 2 tablix , and I have a filter called sections ( multi valued filter ) ,

I want to make my report sections appear based on the selection of the filter ,

Example : 
tablix_1 will appear if i select "Section 1" from filter
tablix_2 will appear if i select "Section 2" from filter

Both grid will appear if i select both sections from filter

I'm suppose to put an experession in the visible property of the tablix, to set the hidden property based on the value selected from the filter ,

My problem is how can i say "if the value of the parameter is ( section 1 & 2) , the IN option is not valid, and also i tried index ( it only work with paramter.value(0)) , i want to search of the selected values .

Answer (score 1):

If you want an item to only be displayed when `Section 1` is selected, use an expression like this for the **Hidden** property:

```
=IIf(Join(Parameters!sections.Value, ",") like "*Section 1*", False, True)
```

Adjust for the different sections as required.

Comment: Did this help with your issue at all?